# Problema com select em meu controller

Tags: laravel

Olá, estou fazendo join entre duas tabela para exibir o nome do usuario na view, mas esta dando o seguinte erro:

`Call to a member function select() on string`

**Meu controller:**

```
$postagens = Postagens::all()->sortByDesc('created_at')
    ->join('users','users.id' , '=', 'postagens.usuario' )
    ->select('users.name as nomeusuario')
    ->get();
    return view('index',compact('postagens'));
```

**A view:**

```
@foreach ($postagens as $pubs)
@postagens()
        @slot('titulo')
            {{$pubs['nomePost']}}
        @endslot
    @slot('descricao')
        {{$pubs['descricao']}}
    @endslot
    @slot('dia')
        {{$pubs['created_at']}}
    @endslot

    @slot('id')
        {{$pubs['nomeusuario']}}
    @endslot        
@endpostagens
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função [all()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#collections) é para retornar uma coleção de valores obtidos de sua base de dados. Então quando você declara `Postagens::all()`, será retornado uma coleção de todos os registros existentes na tabela configurada.

```
SELECT * FROM postagens
```

Note que em seu código, você utiliza o método `join()`, este método pertence ao [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#introduction) do Laravel, então para utilizá-lo seu código deve estar dessa maneira.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

...

$postagens = DB::table('postagens') //Nome da tabela postagens
    ->select('users.name as nomeusuario')
    ->join('users','users.id','=','postagens.usuario')
    ->orderBy('postagens.created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Para utilizar a sua model para a consulta você precisa usar a [Querying Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) do Eloquent ORM.

Comment: deu isso agora: join() expects at most 2 parameters, 4 given

Comment: Resolvi agora deu: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::sortByDesc()

Comment: @joaogabriel97, eu nem notei o erro da função que você escreveu. Não é `sortByDesc` mas sim `orderBy` onde nesta é definida qual o campo e tipo da ordem. Olhe a documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: @joaogabriel97, resolveu o seu problema?